# Proving this is a theorem of $\mathbf{S4.4}$: modal logic

Tags: proof-verification, logic, modal-logic

**Problem:** The system $\mathbf{S4.4}$ of modal logic adds to the system $\mathbf{S4}$ the axiom $(A \wedge \Diamond \Box A) \rightarrow \Box A$. Show that $$ (\Diamond A \wedge \Diamond B) \rightarrow (\Diamond (A \wedge \Diamond B) \vee \Diamond (B \wedge \Diamond A))$$ is a theorem of $\mathbf{S4.4}$.

**Attempt:** In $\mathbf{S4}$ I have the following additional axioms:

(i) $\Box A \rightarrow A$

(ii) $\Box A \rightarrow \Box \Box A$ and their duals.

Furthermore, axioms of minimal temporal logic include axioms like $\Box (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\Box A \rightarrow \Box B)$ and stuff like $(\Box A_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \Box A_n) \leftrightarrow \Box (A_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge A_n)$.

To prove the statement, it is enough to prove $(\Diamond A \wedge \Diamond B) \rightarrow \Diamond (A \wedge \Diamond B)$. It is enough to prove the dual, which is $ \Box (A \vee \Box B) \rightarrow \Box A \vee \Box B$.

Now, the axiom $\Box (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\Box A \rightarrow \Box B)$ is equivalent to $$ \Box (A \vee B) \rightarrow (\Diamond A \vee \Box B). $$ Performing a substitution, I get $$ \Box (A \vee \Box B) \rightarrow (\Diamond A \vee \Box \Box B). $$  Now, taking the dual of the additional axiom of $\mathbf{S4.4}$, I see that $$ \Diamond A \rightarrow A \vee \Box \Diamond A.$$

Furthermore, using axiom (i), I see that $\Box \Box B \rightarrow \Box B$ where I also used substitution. Therefore, I know that $$ \Box (A \vee \Box B) \rightarrow A \vee \Box \Diamond A \vee \Box B. $$ This is almost what I need, except that I need to prove somehow that $$ A \vee \Box \Diamond A \rightarrow \Box A $$ and this is where I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not erroneous, though the desired final implication 
$$A\vee\Box\Diamond A\rightarrow \Box A$$
is not a theorem of S4.4. It is easy to build a two-state Kripke model of S4.4 in which the first state sees the second but not vice versa, and a proposition $A$ which holds for the first state, but not the second. In this model, this implication fails.

Unfortunatly, the first step already doomed you,S4.4 does not prove 
$$\Diamond A\wedge\Diamond B\rightarrow\Diamond( A\wedge\Diamond B)$$
The counterexample form above is a counterexample here as well.

So let us assume
$$\Diamond A\wedge\Diamond B \wedge \neg \Diamond( A\wedge\Diamond B)$$
which is equivalent to 
$$\Diamond A\wedge\Diamond B \wedge \Box (\neg A\vee\Box \neg B)$$
and recall that we want to show 
$$\Diamond(\Diamond A\wedge B)$$
from the above.
From T we get $\neg A\vee\Box\neg B$ and as $\Diamond B$ holds, $\neg A$. 
I claim 
$$\Box\Diamond A$$
If this fails,
$$\Diamond\Box\neg A$$
and from S4.4 and $\neg A$ we conclude 
$$\Box\neg A$$
which contradicts $\Diamond A$. Thus we have 
$$\Diamond B\wedge\Box\Diamond A$$
and hence 
$$\Diamond(B\wedge \Diamond A)$$
as desired.